# MySQL: Replace "group by" with a join

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm developing on a Laravel project right now and I have to handle some SQL stuff.

As I want to stay MySQL in the strict mode, I have to replace the following query with a query without a "group by".
I've read, that I can reach this through a join, but I really have no idea how to do this in this example.

At first, here is my example table called "fruits". Please don't mind about the redundancy, I get the data as they are:

```
fruitName     | fruitModel
--------------------------
Banana (Nr 1) | Banana
Banana (Nr 2) | Banana
Banana (Nr 3) | Banana
Apple (Nr 1)  | Apple
Apple (Nr 2)  | Apple
Strawberry    | Strawberry
Banana (Nr 4) | Banana
```

I want to get the following table:

```
fruitName     | fruitModel
--------------------------
Banana (Nr 1) | Banana
Apple (Nr 1)  | Apple
Strawberry    | Strawberry
```

So for every fruitModel I want to have *one* fruitName. It is not relevant, what exact fruitName I get. So a result like the following would be okay, too:

```
fruitName     | fruitModel
--------------------------
Banana (Nr 3) | Banana
Apple (Nr 2)  | Apple
Strawberry    | Strawberry
```

I have a query, which works perfectly to reach this, but I have to build a query without the "group by" part as in strict mode every selected column have to show up in the "group by". Here is my current query:

```
SELECT fruitModel, fruitName FROM fruits GROUP BY fruitModel
```

Does anyone has an idea on how to replace the "group by" part by some join stuff?
Thank you.

Comment: "It is not relevant what exact fruitName I get." This kind of statement is often symptomatic of a poor data model. It *should* matter!

Comment: What you ask is not possible without a group by. You have not understood the problem.

Comment: Maybe it is a poor data model, but if I get data like this from an API, I have to live with it. Furthermore, in other parts of the application, the exact value is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` is fine, because you do want an aggregation per fruit model. Only you forgot to apply an aggregation function on the fruit names. Use `ANY_VALUE` for this:

```
SELECT fruitModel, ANY_VALUE(fruitName) AS fruitName FROM fruits GROUP BY fruitModel;
```

`ANY_VALUE` tells the DBMS that you are fine with any value for that group.

(As you also tagged MariaDB: I don't think that MariaDB features `ANY_VALUE`. So for this DBMS simply use `MIN` or `MAX` instead.)

Comment: Thank you. The problem is, that I am using [sql strict mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) which does not allow to select multiple columns, but grouping only by one column.

Comment: @LeoV `ANY_VALUE` is an aggregation function. `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` forbids nonaggregate nongrouped columns

Comment: @Leo V: I doubt that. I don't know "strict mode", but I can only imagine it means that you must apply an aggregate function on non-grouped columns. Have you tried my query?

Comment: I'm sure. Nevertheless, your answer with "min" / "max" works for me, as this is an aggregation function, not a column, as @Caleth said.
Thank you.